# Can't reopen Django File as rb

Tags: python, django

Why does reopening a django.core.files File as binary not work?

```
from django.core.files import File

f = open('/home/user/test.zip')
test_file = File(f)
test_file.open(mode="rb")
test_file.read()
```

This gives me the error `'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x82 in position 14: invalid start byte` so opening in 'rb' obviously didn't work. The reason I need this is because I want to open a FileField as binary

Comment: You need to open it immediately with binary mode, so `f = open('/home/user/test.zip', mode='rb')` Otherwise the file will wrap it to the file handler which will aim to read it as text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to [**`open(…)`** [Python-doc]](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) the underlying file handler in binary mode, so:

```
with open('/home/user/test.zip', mode='rb') as f:
    test_file = File(f)
    test_file.open(mode='rb')
    test_file.read()
```

Without opening it in binary mode, the underlying reader will try to read this as text, and thus error on bytes that are not a utf-8 code points.

Comment: Hmm so if the initial file saved in the Django model FileField was not saved with mode 'rb', how do I open it in binary without decoding?

Comment: @JohannesPertl: if it is in binary, and you save it with `'w'` it will raise an error on saving it, since it expects *text*, not *bytes*.

Comment: You can not put a binary reader on top of a text reader, since the `test_file` basically is a thin wrapper to the file handler, and thus if that is reading bytes as text and fails, there is not much the `File` can do to fix this.